# How do I enforce atomic database updates in Django?

Tags: django

I am developing a course registration website. A user can enroll in a class, during which he/she incurs an enrollment fee for that class:

```
class.add(student);
student.get_profile().balance += class.tuition
```

How do I make sure that these two operations are atomic? For instance, I do not want the second action to be performed if the first action failed to be performed (due to say overuse of memory).

Comment: Have you tried Django transaction Middleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: @husbas: You missed. A little lower please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django transaction [Middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions) would allow you to do so.